# ./gradlew run BUILD FAILED

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, gradle, webdriver

I have my build.gradle file set up and my project is working good so far. The problem now is when i run ./gradlew run, it fails with the error :

> What went wrong:
>   Execution failed for task ':run'.
>   Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
>
> ./gradlew build BUILD SUCCESSFULLY, Any clue as to why, Have also tried to check previous thread but all to no avail.Below is my gradle.build file:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'application'

mainClassName = 'src.main.java.Functional.TestRun'

repositories {
mavenCentral()
}
sourceSets {
selenium
}

jar {
baseName = 'gs-gradle'
version =  '0.1.0'
manifest {
    attributes 'Main-Class': 'main.java.Functional.TestRun'
   }
}
compileJava {
sourceCompatibility = 1.7
targetCompatibility = 1.7
}

dependencies {
seleniumCompile 'junit:junit:4.11'
seleniumCompile 'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:2.45.0'
seleniumCompile 'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-server:2.45.0'    
compile fileTree(dir: 'libraries', include: '*.jar') 
}
task jettyDaemon(type: org.gradle.api.plugins.jetty.JettyRun) {
daemon = true
}
task selenium(type: Test, dependsOn: jettyDaemon) {
testClassesDir = sourceSets.selenium.output.classesDir
classpath = sourceSets.selenium.runtimeClasspath
}
eclipse {
classpath {
    plusConfigurations += configurations.seleniumCompile
}
}
task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
gradleVersion = '2.3'
}
```

> ERROR:

```
ola@ola-VirtualBox:~/workspace/mainsite_automation$ ./gradlew run
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:run
Error: Could not find or load main class src.main.java.Functional.TestRun
:run FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':run'.
> Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/java'' finished           
with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --     
debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 2.185 secs
```

Comment: The key is in this one: "Could not find or load main class src.main.java.Functional.TestRun". Something wrong with the class path? The test classes are missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `mainClassName = 'src.main.java.Functional.TestRun'` in your build.gradle by `mainClassName = Functional.TestRun'`. You should also fix your manifest entry.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Have made the changes but still getting same error. is this what you mean by the manifest entry? `jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'main.java.Functional.Test_Run'
    }
}` right? ,...... Its working now... Tanx

Comment: ..... So the way i have my test written is that i specify the testcase to run. So anytime i want to run a testcase, i will have to go and change the test in the code. Hope that is OK for now?. Or is there any other way to run all the testcases at a go, without having to go to my code?

Comment: Well, two things. **1.** I meant you should change in your manifest definition also to `'Functional.Test_Run'`, but I think you can maybe even leave it out completely, I think it should also pick up the `mainClassName` automatically. **2.** Normally you do not run tests with the `run` task, but with the `test` task that automatically runs all your tests if they are JUnit tests and you have them in `main/test/java/` and you can even give the `test` task as parameter which test to run if it is only one test you want to run. If your tests are normal runnable classes, you could specify ...

Comment: ... multiple `run` tasks for your different main methods. Alternatively you can also use a project property and then specify it on the commandline to control which test is run with `-P testClass=Functional.Test_Run` and then having `mainClassName = testClass` in your build file, optionally having a default value e. g. in `gradle.properties` or in the build file with checking `project.hasProperty('testClass')`

Comment: Thanks so much for these.... One more thing, as am new to Gradle, just asking as many questions as possible, once my code runs fine after using run, can i add the wrapper to jenkins then , and other test team can build my project from there?

Comment: Dunno how your situation is exaclty, but yes, usually you check in the Gradle Wrapper and then always use the gradle wrapper to build the project. This way the only thing you need to kick off the build is an installed Java. Gradle is automatically downloaded in the version the build is designed for and runs with that.